# Replace values in df/matrix based on another matrix/df in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I have two data frames, one contains numbers, and the second is binary, both are the same size. I would now like to replace all numbers in data frame A with `NA` if the corresponding variable in data frame B is 0 and not 1. If it is 1 the number should remain unchanged.
How do I go about that?

df A

```
   A  B  C
1  34 32 12
2  52 23 34
```

df B

```
   A  B  C
1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

desired result

```
   A  B  C
1  34 32 12
2  na na 34
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're working with matrices, it's as simple as `mat1[which(mat2 == 0)] <- NA`.

Comment: Ah, even better. It takes surprisingly long to get into this subsetting and indexing way of R...

Comment: N.B: you don't need `which`

Answer (score 6):

I found my answer, after reading the docs I thought the replace command worked only for vectors, but the following does the trick:

```
new.df <- replace(A.df, B.df == 0, "NaN")
```